# Истинная правда: грамотно ли это?

Tags: грамотная-речь, плеоназм

Часто, чтобы подтвердить истинность своих слов, человек говорит: "Истинная правда!" Насколько вообще это литературно и грамотно? Ведь самый натуральный плеоназм.

Answer (score 4):

В русском языке *истина* и *правда* — это разные вещи. Истина — безусловна, единственна и недостижима. Правда же зависит от того, чья она, при каких обстоятельствах применима, да к тому же у каждого своя.

Из различий значения слов и родилось данное сочетание. Говоря *истинная правда*, человек утверждает, что он не только высказывает своё виденье, но и претендует на то, что это виденье универсальное и единственно верное. Так что я не считаю данное словосочетание плеоназмом.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, плеоназм весьма слабый, отнюдь не "натуральный", во-вторых, не всякий плеоназм, даже будь он трижды натуральным, - очевидное зло, только неуклюже избыточный.
Я не склонен видеть в "истине" в данном контексте что-то философское,хотя в принципе такое различие действительно есть: истина - знание, правда - откровенность; истина объективна, правда может быть субъективна  и проч.
Но здесь дело совсем в другом. Без всякой метафизики
Истинная - здесь не в этом значении, это просто оценка, повышающая уровень правдивости высказывания. Истинная значит неопровержимая, очевидная, безусловная.
"Истинная ложь" - столь же возможное сочетание. Кстати, уже одно это снимает все сомнения в том, что выражение - не плеоназм.

Answer (score 2):

В выражениях "истинная правда", "истинная ложь", "истинный факт" и подобных слово "истинный" служит как усиление, то есть самая что ни на есть правда (факт), в которой невозможно сомневаться, а не чье-то субъективное мнение, выдумка. Можно, конечно, рассматривать это как плеоназм, но язык — не математика, не точная наука, он частенько допускает плеоназм в целях большей убедительности, большего эмоционального эффекта, оставаясь при этом вполне литературным.
Что же касается слов "истина" и "правда", то они являются синонимами, что указывается в словарях, а выражение "своя правда" означает в действительности, что у каждого из оппонентов могут быть свои аргументы, которые могут оказаться резонными, то есть в чем-то, возможно, прав один, в чем-то — другой. А правда, она же истина, все же одна, хотя мы ее можем и не знать.
Выражения "истинная правда", "истинный факт" звучат нелепо в научной статье, но вполне уместны в ежедневном общении и литературной речи. Тип речи часто является определяющим.

Comment: Добавлю. Сначала цитата: "Правда — многозначный термин, используемый либо как синоним слову истина. либо как синоним слова справедливость". В нашем контексте - именно истина. Несогласные - читайте справочники и словари. Да, плеоназм, но в определенных случаях это вполне нормально. Английской - мой второй язык, и выражение "each and every one" является таким же плеоназмом, но никому в голову не приходит обвинять говорящего это в неграмотности и нелитературности. Цель здесь, как и у известного "never ever", как и у множества других русских, английских и прочих выражений - эмоциональное усиление.

Answer (score 1):

Принимая вышеизложенную точку зрения, не могу не сказать, что в словарях синонимов первым к слову ПРАВДА указывается ИСТИНА. Так что на этом основании можно все же считать выражение "ИСТИННАЯ ПРАВДА" плеоназмом.